# Controller для переиспользуемого шаблона laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Я только начал изучать laravel и столкнулся с проблемой в контроллерах.
Есть шаблон /dashboard который наследует переиспользуемый шаблон header и footer.
Для шаблона /dashboard есть маршрут с вызовом контроллера и вся логика происходит там, но мне нужно отделить логику от dashboad и использовать свой контроллер в header, так как при переходе на другую страницу, выходит ошибка, говорящая, что переменная в шаблоне есть но в контроллере она не задана. Искал долго, но не нашел или не понял как это сделать

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@dashboard' );




class DashboardController extends Controller{

public function dashboard(Request $request){
    //Передача переменных в шаблон
    $dataVar = [
        'cookieThemeCont' => Cookie::get('theme'),
        'cookieSidebarCont' => Cookie::get('minSidebar')
    ];

    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('dashboard', $dataVar);
    }
    return redirect('login');
}
```

Вывод в header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>{{$cookieThemeCont}}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      @yield('content')
   </body>
</html>
```

Файл dashboard

```
@extends('layouts.main_dashboard')
@section('content')
    <h1>Текст</h1>
@endsection
```

Comment: А как этот `header` выглядит? И что на вьюхе dashboard? Без полной информации это пальцем в небо просто тыкать.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wu6uw3 и https://prnt.sc/wu7368 . я весь код не стал пихать, очень много, упростил

Comment: Вот этот же код, только в вопрос сдублировать лучше, тогда смогу дать ответ с примером.

Comment: хорошо, сделал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Laravel (да и не только), есть такое понятие как `Template Inheritance`, прочитать про него более подробно можно в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#layouts-using-template-inheritance).

Если взять пример вашего кода, то что нужно было сделать:

В главном шаблоне, который `main_dashboard`, прописать следующее:

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

Вместо:

```
<title>{{$cookieThemeCont}}</title>
```

И тогда уже в ваш шаблон `dashboard` вы передаете свою переменную `$cookieThemeCont` и там её используете:

```
@section('title', $cookieThemeCont)
```

Только так и нужно передавать с наследуемых шаблонов в ролительские, больше примеров есть в документации, есть ещё похожие варианты с `stack`, советую тоже ознакомится.

Если нужно же передавать данные по всем шаблонам, то можно воспользоваться шарингом (подробнее [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)). К примеру в `AppServiceProvider` написать:

```
View::share('cookieThemeCont', Cookie::get('theme'));
```

И переменная будет доступна везде, но лучше таким не злоупотреблять, есть ещё вариант с `@inject`, но он мне кажется ещё хуже.

Comment: Я получаю куки и вывожу в хедер. Если я сделаю route на страницу /about, то в контроллере AboutController мне нужно опять создавать и передавать массив $dataVar во view, что бы оттуда отдать в header. Хотелось бы задать один раз эти переменные и в других контроллерах их не использовать

Comment: Это другая история уже, тут лучше использовать View::share, дополнил ответ.

Comment: А зачем секции?? Есть стак и пуш

Answer (score 1):

А можно так. Вставить в title: `{{ isset($cookieThemeCont) ? $cookieThemeCont : '' }}`